# Question about CPU manipulation with RF waves

Tags: radio-frequency

Is it possible that by sending a specifically modulated RF wave, you can manipulate the flow of electricity to the CPU, and maybe cause binary code Execution? Like typing something like Hello?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly derange the function of digital circuitry with sufficiently powerful RF. The consequences may allow you to decode hidden information. However, getting it to do something as organized as typing "hello" is extremely difficult.

Comment: Since the wavelength of radio waves is much larger than features in a CPU, extremely difficult sounds optimistic. I would go with not possible.

Comment: @mmesser314 CPUs have intricate external connections, and you can certainly induce substantial RF currents in those connections. Different connections resonate at different frequencies, and there's also the time domain to exploit. I hesitate to say impossible as this is the kind of thing where clever people can sometimes figure out a way. The jargon is "fault injection attack".

Comment: Is it possible that using custom software, it creates a high power RF wave that can cause Fault Injection attacks on systems and also code Execution?

Comment: @AndyCrypto Well, to *make* a high power RF wave, you need to efficiently couple a high power supply to an RF electromagnetic field. That's not something you can do with software alone.

Comment: I wonder, could this happen over long distances? Since technically RF waves can travel long distances

Comment: @AndyCrypto Well, in the far field the $1/r^2$ law applies.

Comment: Has there been any incidents of what I just mentioned before? If so, do you have any links so that I can examine?

Comment: While John Doty is right, this question is a little like asking if you could make an earthquake that jostled a car factory just right to make it produce the wrong color cars. It might be possible, but it wouldn't be by jostling the paint controls and nothing else. More likely by breaking a tank of paint and spilling it over cars. Not a very realistic way to hack a computer.